# TypeError: can't pickle _ssl._SSLSocket objects

Tags: python-2.7, neo4j, pickle

I am working with Python 2.7 version. When I am trying to create a session in neo4j.v1 bolt driver to push the nodes to graph, I am facing this error. As far I understood, this is a environment issue. If it that true, how can I solve this problem. I don't have any idea of this error and don't know how to debug this. Any suggestion a lehman can understand is appreciated.

Comment: are you using `multiprocessing` or something else that requires inter-process communication to share a driver object?

Comment: No. I am not using any multiprocessing directly. But there might be chance that the libraries I am using Neo4j Bolt Driver and PySpark 1.6 using that internally.

Comment: PySpark is your culprit there, but I haven't worked with it enough to tell you how to fix it. You can't pickle neo4j driver instances, though, so make sure you instantiate them inside the worker process using an initializer of some sort.